# Module of dimension zero over a local ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $(A,m)$ be a Noetherian local ring and let $M$ be an $A$-module of dimension $0$ ($\dim M=\dim A/\operatorname{Ann}M$). Then every element of $M$ is annihilated by a power of $m$.

I would appreciate some help proving this. Thanks.

Comment: For $M=A$ see  [An equivalent condition for zero dimensional Noetherian local rings](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929396/an-equivalent-condition-for-zero-dimensional-noetherian-local-rings)

Comment: Actually you don't need $M$ finitely generated.

Comment: But for non-finitely generated modules there are two definitions of $\dim M$ which can differ (and this is why I've asked you what definition are using). However, they coincide for $M$ f.g.

Comment: @user26857 and the other one is "the supremum of lengths of chains of prime ideals in the SuppM"? Just checking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\dim M=0$ we have $\dim A/\operatorname{Ann}M=0$, so $A/\operatorname{Ann}M$ is a local artinian ring and you are done.

Comment: That's the definition I'm using, but I don't see how I'm done. Could you elaborate perhaps, if you have the time? Thank you.

Comment: @baltazar An artinian ring has the property that its Jacobson radical is nilpotent; see  Proposition 5.3 [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~mitchell/Algh/jac.pdf). (Don't worry, the same proof works for commutative rings.)

Comment: Ah, got it now. So then $m^n/$Ann$M = 0$ for some $n$ and therefore $m^n=$Ann$(M)$. Right? Thanks.

Comment: @baltazar Actually $m^n\subseteq\operatorname{Ann}M$ for some $n\ge 1$.

Comment: Right. Thanks, all clear now.